# ajax search for multiple table join in php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I am using ajax for search functionality. There are dependent multiple table join.
I am not getting proper result.I want unique result for search.Below my code is given:

```
$this->db->distinct('table2.sname,table3.cname');
$this->db>select('table1.stname,table2.*,table3.*,table4.*,table5.*');
$this->db->from('table5');
$this->db->join('table1','table1.stid=table2.stid');
$this->db->join('table2','table2.sid=table3.sid');
$this->db->join('table3','table3.cid=table4.cid');
$this->db->join('table4','table4.tid=table5.tid');
$this->db->or_like("table1.stname",$keyword);
$this->db->or_like("table2.sname",$keyword);
$this->db->or_like("table3.cname",$keyword);
$this->db->or_like("table4.tname",$keyword);
$this->db->or_like("table5.stoname",$keyword);
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: unique result . . you mean the first result of the query or the query fails because return  more then  row ?

Comment: Your first `$this->db->or_like()` should be `$this->db->like()` because it is the first one in the query. Also you need to return the `result_array` which you can do by typing `return $query->result_array();` at the end of your code.

Comment: Also what is the result you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I am searching the typed keyword  in all tables which are join. But I am not getting proper result for all typed keyword

Answer (score 0):

If you need  the first rows  form select then you could use limit(1)

```
<?php 

    $this->db->distinct('table2.sname,table3.cname');
     $this->db>select('table1.stname,table2.*,table3.*,table4.*,table5.*');
     $this->db->from('table5');
     $this->db->join('table1','table1.stid=table2.stid');
     $this->db->join('table2','table2.sid=table3.sid');
     $this->db->join('table3','table3.cid=table4.cid');
     $this->db->join('table4','table4.tid=table5.tid');
     $this->db->or_like("table1.stname",$keyword);
     $this->db->or_like("table2.sname",$keyword);
     $this->db->or_like("table3.cname",$keyword);
     $this->db->or_like("table4.tname",$keyword);
     $this->db->or_like("table5.stoname",$keyword);

    $this->db->limit(1);

     $query = $this->db->get();

?>
```

or if you need  all query result  the return  the result()

```
<?php 

    $this->db->distinct('table2.sname,table3.cname');
     $this->db>select('table1.stname,table2.*,table3.*,table4.*,table5.*');
     $this->db->from('table5');
     $this->db->join('table1','table1.stid=table2.stid');
     $this->db->join('table2','table2.sid=table3.sid');
     $this->db->join('table3','table3.cid=table4.cid');
     $this->db->join('table4','table4.tid=table5.tid');
     $this->db->or_like("table1.stname",$keyword);
     $this->db->or_like("table2.sname",$keyword);
     $this->db->or_like("table3.cname",$keyword);
     $this->db->or_like("table4.tname",$keyword);
     $this->db->or_like("table5.stoname",$keyword);


     $query = $this->db->get();

     return $query->result();

?>
```

Comment: I want all result for query not single row.

Comment: @PRIYANKAMORE  answer  updated .. hope is what you are looking for